# Where is my RDP certificate?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

we received official SSL Certificate which we installed on remote Windows 2019 Server. But when I try to RDP to this remote server , I get warning that the certificate are not valid. Moreover the date of expiry also does not match with the one showing in official certificates. I hence wish to know which certificate we see in this warning. I tried to search in MMC for the certficiate in terms of issued for the said remote computer. But all search reasults show the correct official certificates. Where is this certficiate then?

@spikey_richie Yes I installed it to local machine using mmc.

```
Specific steps : On the Remote Windows Server computer, click Start and type mmc.exe.
In the MMC window, go to File > Add/Remove Snap-in.
In the Add or Remove Snap-ins window, select Certificates and click Add.
In the Certificates snap-in window, select Computer account, click Next, select Local computer, and click Finish.
Click [+] next to Certificates > Personal > Certificates
Right click on Certificates and select All Tasks > Import
Click Next
Click Browse
Select the .cer, .crt, or .pfx you would like to import. Click Open.
Click Next
Select Automatically select the certificate store based on the type of certificate.
Click Finish & OK

I could see the new Certificates in the respective folders   E.g.  under Personal, Trusted root certification authorities and as well under Remote Desktop.    Also followed this workaround "[link] https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/core-infrastructure-and-security/remote-desktop-connection-rdp-certificate-warnings/ba-p/259301"  both the command were executed  `1. $path = (Get-WmiObject -class "Win32_TSGeneralSetting" -Namespace root\cimv2\terminalservices -Filter "TerminalName='RDP-tcp'").__path`
`2. Set-WmiInstance -Path $path -argument @{SSLCertificateSHA1Hash="$Thumbprint"})   But the second command gives
)"Invalid Parameter"`
```

Output:

```
`C:\Users\Administrator> $path = (Get-WmiObject -class "Win32_TSGeneralSetting" -Namespace root\cimv2\terminalservices -Filter "TerminalName='RDP-tcp'").__path

C:\Users\Administrator> Set-WmiInstance -Path $path -argument @{SSLCertificateSHA1Hash="0bedcc601d6f7XXXXX"}
Set-WmiInstance : Invalid parameter
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-WmiInstance -Path $path -argument @{SSLCertificateSHA1Hash="0bedc ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [Set-WmiInstance], ManagementException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : SetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetWmiInstance`
```

Ok further questions are,

> ```
>  *Does the certificate include the Remote Desktop Authentication policy?*
> ```

How to check this?

> *Have you tried creating a new RDP profile to the server?*

No I have not. How do I do this? It is a standalone system with Microsoft Windows Server 2019  Standard operating system. No domain controller or so.

Comment: Did you install the certificate to the machine store, or the users store? Best to use `certlm.msc` for importing the certificate, when it's not user-specific.

Comment: You mean on remote server , yes I have been installing the certificate many times till now. But hard luck.

Comment: You still didn't answer my question. Have you installed the certificate into the local machine certificate store, or a users certificate store?

Comment: You have to install the certificate on both machines. Additionally, are getting a certificate error, sounds like the certificate might have issues

Comment: @spikey_richie  please see the original post for my comments.

Comment: Does your certificate include the “Remote Desktop Authentication” (1.3.6.1.4.1.311.54.1.2) application policy? Did you change the RDP configuration so it points at the new certificate?

Comment: @ramhound  The SSL Certificate is official hence I would like to believe that this is not the issue. And yes I installed them on both the machines.

Comment: @SachinH - “official” doesn’t mean anything.  Does the certificate include the Remote Desktop Authentication policy?  You indicated you are being told a certificate is not valid, so at some point, you were using that certificate.  Have you tried creating a new RDP profile to the server?  You should edit your question, at this point, it’s very difficult to follow

Comment: @danielB Official Certificate shows this.... 1.3.6.1.4.1.4329.99.1.1.1.1.0
1.3.6.1.4.1.4329.99.2.2.1.1.0   Not sure what does it mean....sorry i am not much into Windows. How do I  change RDP Configuration to point to new certificate. Its just there under RDP Folder in MMC.

Comment: @SachinH - I am already notified of every single comment you submit.  I don't need to be pinged directly.  Your certificate wasn't created to support RDP.  You should [edit] your question instead of submitting commentary.  How you create a new RDP profile, on the client, is well documented.